# Default value to core data attributes (column) for iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

**Current Approach**

- I set the default value of the attribute directly to the data model file using the inspector.

**Problem**

- I have enum for the values a particular attribute can take.
- I am worried maintaining them at a later stage might be difficult.
- Suppose if I decide to change the enum values, then I would have to manually go the inspector and change it.
- Since I have quite a number of attributes based on enum values, it becomes difficult.

**Question**

- How can I add default values to core data attributes programmatically ?
- Is there any alternative to do this, so that maintenance would be easier ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subclass your NSManagedObject and set default values in `awakeFromInsert`

[Related docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html) (see *Object Life-Cycle*)

Comment: thanks, but in my project there is an entity which only contains 1 row, and when the user first installs the app, 1 row would be inserted. According to my code, when the next version of the app goes live, no row would be added, so `awakeFromInsert` wouldn't be invoked. Therefore the default value for the newly added attribute wouldn't be set.

Comment: well if no row is added, why do you care about default value?

Comment: What I meant is that, the app would ONLY contain 1 row of data (like static data). This row would be added when the app is first installed. When the user updates to a later version, the app will not insert a new row, bcuz a row already exists. The problem arises bcuz the new attributes default value wouldn't be set bcuz the logic would be in `awakeFromInsert`

Comment: Then default value is irrelevant, sounds like you need to change some values in your existing data.

Comment: You are correct, I was wrong. Default values take effect ONLY while inserting a new record and if I don't explicitly mention the value. It has no effect for an already created record and new column with default value added. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: If you're only creating one instance (row) of an entity, why are you even using Core Data? What purpose does that serve?

Answer (score 4):

Everything you can do graphically in the Core Data model editor you can do using the classes Core Data provides for creating/introspecting a managed object model. For this use case, you can use [`NSEntityDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003604) to look up an entity, its [`properties`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEntityDescription/properties) or [`propertiesByName`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEntityDescription/propertiesByName) accessors to find the [`NSAttributeDescription`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSAttributeDescription) for the attribute you're interested, and [`setDefaultValue:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSAttributeDescription_Class/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributeDescription/setDefaultValue%3a) to do the same thing the Core Data model editor does.

You might find this the most appropriate way to do what you're looking for. Or, as @DimitryShevchenko notes, you can initialize values in your `NSManagedObject` subclass' [`awakeFromInsert`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/awakeFromInsert) method -- which way you choose might depend on your workflow or other requirements of your application.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried using `NSEntityDescription` but I get the following exception `NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't modify an immutable model.` I was setting the default values after the Database is up. When should I be setting the default values ?

Comment: I have used `UIManagedDocument` in my project, and I try to set the default values before `UIManagedDocument persistentStoreOptions` is set and yet I get the same error

Comment: Definitely before db is up

Comment: Yes, I tried before the DB is up. I set the default values immediately after UIManagedDocument was allocated. I did it even before persistentStoreOptions was set. I still get the same error